# Own nameservers on shared hosting: subdomains on different hosts

Tags: domain-name-system, shared-hosting, subdomain

I imagine this question has been asked before, but I can't find it.

I have three domain names, `example.com`, `example.net` (this one has a bunch of subdomains), and `example.org`. Currently, all three are on shared hosting, and use the host's standard nameservers).

I have bought shared hosting at another company, because I want to move some sites from the USA to the UK, but I'm not using it yet.

What I'd like to do is

- change the nameservers for all domains to `life.example.net`,
  `universe.example.net`, and `everything.example.net`;
- move `example.com` to the UK host;
- move some, but not all, subdomains of `example.net` to the UK host.

I don't have my own server. Both the US and the UK hosts are shared hosting, so I imagine I'll need a third-party company to run nameservers. Or perhaps not. I know some hosts allow you to have your own nameservers as aliases of their nameservers, but that probably wouldn't allow me to move some stuff to the other host.

Also, the US host, when it receives a request for a subdomain which doesn't exist, just serves up the main site. That's quite handy, and I'd like to keep it. So I'd like to set up a record like `*.example.net` pointing to the US host, so that `random-query.example.net` gets the US host, while `existing-domain.example.net` will get either the US or the UK host, depending on what I've set.

I'm pretty sure the above is possible, but I have no idea how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who's the DNS host?  Most of the DNS hosting companies that I've looked at support setting up child DNS.  As long as they do you can point the child names to the other hosting providers IP address.  You don't need to change the DNS host to change the company that is hosting the website.

All you need to do is change the A records in the current hosting company for life.example.net to the new public IP.

Comment: The US hosting company is also providing the nameservers. Some of the domains were bought through them, and they're managing everything for those. The ones that were bought elsewhere, I simply provided their nameservers to the company I bought the domains from.

Comment: That's fine.  As long as you can edit the DNS zone file in some way you can make the needed changes.

Comment: I'll ask the US host whether they can do this for me. They may well be able to.